# troublesome element with an href attribute

Tags: xslt, href, attr

xslt works as long as i do **not** include the  element and it's children.  Something to do with the href= i think...

```
Can anyone see how to get the template to work while still leaving the <links> node in??
```

I can't adjust the xml format at all.

Here is the sample xmls and template below.  notice the bolded links element with the href attribute.  if i delete that out things work ok.  if i leave it in it fails.

thanks in advance for your help.
JB.

```
XML:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<oicMessage xmlns="http://abc.com/oic/2012/04/message">
    <header>
        <publisher>Gentle</publisher>
        <messageId>8685217a-9237-464d-8a94-33d7f1a41542</messageId>
        <eventCorrelationId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</eventCorrelationId>
        <messageDate>2013-10-14T16:00:00.0000000+00:00</messageDate>
        <receivedTimestamp />
        <contextId>Unknown</contextId>
        <messageName>JHB-3C Up to 7 Stable Period Found</messageName>
        <messageDescription>JHB-3C Up to 7 Stable Period Found</messageDescription>
        <messageTypeUri>oic/rtrm/event/stableperiod/uptosevenfound</messageTypeUri>
    </header>
    <payload>
        <notificationMessage>
            <reason />
            <action />
            <equipment>JHB-3C</equipment>
            <severityName>None</severityName>
            <severityColour>FFFFFF</severityColour>
            <severityOrdinal>0</severityOrdinal>
            **<links>
                <link href="[BIGFISH Server URL]/eplant/default.asp?    page_id=24001&amp;GPW=JHB-3C&amp;PA_PWELL=JHB-3C&amp;time=1381766400">BIGFISH Page</link>
            </links>**
            <notificationData>
                <group name="Gentle">
                    <request>
                        <start>2013-10-14T15:00:00.0000000+00:00</start>
                        <end>2013-10-14T16:00:00.0000000+00:00</end>
                        <sampleMethod>Average</sampleMethod>
                        <interval>60</interval>
                    </request>
                    <timeseriesdata>
                        <name namingsystem="BF">JHB-3C:BHT.PDHG.degC</name>
                        <displayName>Temperature Input</displayName>
                        <unit>degC</unit>
                        <value time="2013-10-14T16:00:00.0000000+00:00" status="good"/>
                    </timeseriesdata>
                    <timeseriesdata>
                        <name namingsystem="BF"/>
                        <displayName>Pressure Input</displayName>
                        <unit />
                        <value time="2013-10-14T16:00:00.0000000+00:00" status="good">:PHB.PDHG.psia</value>
                    </timeseriesdata>
                    <timeseriesdata>
                        <name namingsystem="BF"/>
                        <displayName>Window Size</displayName>
                        <unit />
                        <value time="2013-10-14T16:00:00.0000000+00:00" status="good">1d</value>
                    </timeseriesdata>
                    <timeseriesdata>                        <name namingsystem="BF">JHB-3C[Gentle]:TopTest.AnalysisPeriod.Duration</name>
                        <displayName>Analysis Period</displayName>
                        <unit />
                        <value time="2013-10-14T16:00:00.0000000+00:00" status="good"/>
                    </timeseriesdata>

                </group>
            </notificationData>
        </notificationMessage>
    </payload>
</oicMessage>
```

XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://abc.com/oic/2012/04/message" >

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="t:oicMessage/t:payload/t:notificationMessage/t:notificationData/t:group/t:timeseriesdata">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="t:name" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="t:value" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet is unaffected by the presence of the links element.

Comment: i wish that was true.  if i leave it in, the style sheet fails.

Comment: Solution: i needed to url encode the characters inside the href value. sorted!

Comment: Perhaps that it is true in your real document, but not in the document and stylesheet as posted, where the link element is irrelevant.